# PHP: Что это за выражение - !${''} и как его использовать?

Tags: php

В [одном из ответов на вопрос о HEREDOC-синтаксисе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36202673/1036370) была приведено интересное выражение:

```
echo <<<EOT
  One month ago was ${!${''} = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 month'))}.
EOT;
```

Что это за "чёрная магия" (по выражению автора)? и как она работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHP есть переменные, которые указывают по имени на другую переменную. Они записываются так `$$var`. То есть мы можем написать такое:

```
$a = 123;
$b = 'a';
print $$b;
```

Этот код выведет `123`

Аналогично мы можем написать `${$b}` - это тоже будет `$a`. И если напишем `${'a'}` - то же самое.

Теперь разберем что там за магия. `${!${''} = 'какая-то ненулевая строка'}` - означает "значение переменной `!'какая-то ненулевая строка'`. Поскольку отрицание ненулевой строки - приводится к пустой строке, то именем переменной будет пустая строка. А мы в этом же выражении этой переменной присвоили нужное нам значение. Поэтому запись `${!${''} = (какое-то выражение)}` эквивалентна переменной, содержащей результат этого выражения (если его результат не приводится к `false`, тогда получим ошибку).

Кстати если захочется таким образом вывести значение, которое может оказаться пустым можно добавить еще немного магии `${!${''} = ${1} = (какое-то выражение)}`

PS. Где там написано, что именем переменной не может быть число?

PPS. Постскриптум - шутка конечно. Я знаю где это написано и знаю что $1 невалидная переменная :)

Comment: > Поскольку отрицание ненулевой строки - пустая строка, то именем переменной будет пустая строка. А мы в этом же выражении этой переменной присвоили нужное нам значение.
—
Не понятно.

Comment: имя переменной в PHP не может быть пустой строкой, и не может начинаться с цифры.

Comment: @Sergiks Факты упрямая вещь `${''} = 'test'; print ${''};` - выводит `abc`

Comment: понял, спасибо! : )   [дискуссия](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318374/is-this-a-php-variable-variable-bug) похожего вопроса на англ.

Comment: @Sergiks насчет имени переменной. Я так понимаю, это ограничение только парсера, к момент доступа к хеш-таблице переменных ключ, видимо, не проверяется